# Disable Auto-White Balance in OpenCV (Android)

Tags: opencv, android-camera, android

I'm working with OpenCV 2.4.9 on Android to track a colored object. Tracking works well but sometimes stops working when Auto White Balance kicks in and readjusts the color temperature of the frame.

**Goal**

Disable or Lock the Auto White Balance feature

-

**Attempted Solution**

There does not seem to be an option in the CameraBridgeViewBase object(mOpenCvCameraView in the Sample OpenCV projects) for disabling Auto White Balance. However, there is the option to disable AWB for the Android Camera object.

```
Camera mCamera = Camera.open( 1 );
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setAutoWhiteBalanceLock(true);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

I've been trying to set the Auto White Balance Lock with the Camera object and then resume business as usual with the CameraBridgeViewBase object and CvCameraViewListener, such as follows.

```
Camera mCamera set parameters like above code block ^
mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
...
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) { ... }
```

### But the parameters set for mCamera do not seem to stick to the CvCameraViewFrames, and the camera keeps auto white balancing.

**Question**

How can one make the Camera object parameters "stick" for the CvCameraViewListener frames?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I had the same problem. You need to set the parameters in the OpenCV source code "JavaCameraView" it should be in your project directory under OpenCV -> Java -> Org -> OpenCv -> Android. In my file there's a comment saying /*Now set Camera Parameters */ and play your params.set.... before the mCamera.setParameters(params).... I hope this is helpful. It didnt seem to work in my main activity either.